# How to connect QToolButtons in QButtonGroup with the QRadioButtons?

Tags: qt, qradiobutton, qtoolbutton

I would like to connect `QToolButtons` in the `QButtonGroup`  with `QRadioButtons` so that they perform same operations.

Here is the code:

```
QToolButton *A=new QToolButton();
A->setCheckable(true);
QButtonGroup *group = new QButtonGroup();

group->addButton(A);
group->addButton(B);

CLASSB *classB=new CLASSB(); 
connect(A, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),classB->radioA , SLOT(toggle()));
connect(B, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), classB->radioB, SLOT(toggle()));

A <->A1 // clicking on tool button should automatically enable radiobutton and should perform the action in radio button
B<->B1
```

I tried `connect(A,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),A1,SLOT(setChecked(bool)));` but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you receive some errors in the _Application Output_?

Comment: Use actions and share them and put them in QActionGroup

Comment: @m7913d  There are no errors in the application output.

Answer (score 0):

If your QToolButton is not checkable it will only pass `false` as signal argument.

From [QAbstractButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) documentation:

> This signal is emitted when the button is activated (i.e. pressed down
>   then released while the mouse cursor is inside the button), when the
>   shortcut key is typed, or when click() or animateClick() is called.
>   Notably, this signal is not emitted if you call setDown(),
>   setChecked() or toggle().
>
> If the button is checkable, checked is true if the button is checked,
>   or false if the button is unchecked.

**Solution** connect to toggle slot:

```
connect(A, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), A1, SLOT(toggle()));
```

Comment: SetCheckable is true and I tried this solution but it doesn't work.